# brocade 6520 san switch is not supporting in hp storage essential

Tags: hp, storage-area-network

I was trying "discover" Brocade 6520 SAN SWITCH in HP Storage essential, is not supported

but the same configuration same speed switch "brocade 6510" is able to discover.

how to make brocade 6520 supported.

Comment: From what I understand the Brocade switch needs to be at factory default in order to be 'discovered' through the broadcast.  has this switch been used before and has a config on it?  If it has, you may want to wipe it and set it to factory defaults.